# How can I dynamically generate a nested list of checkboxes in HTML from JSON?

Tags: javascript, html, json, web

I have a list of issues in a JSON file (see below), returned by a REST API, and I need to generate a nested list of checkboxes from this.

```
{
  "selectedissues": {
    "is1": "issue1",
    "is2": "issue2",
    "is3": {
      "name": "issue3",
      "children": {
        "is4": "issue3a",
        "is5": "issue3b"
      }
    },
    "is6": "issue4"
  }
}
```

Two questions:

1. Is there a better way to get this data? I can change the format with some effort but JSON was just the example I was given. I'd like to to be fairly efficient and understandable and if there's an easier way to pass this data I'd love to hear it.
2. How would I actually go about doing this? I'm completely new to any kind of web dev so am totally lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe a much clenaer structure would be:

```
var json = {
    "selectedissues": [{
        "code": "is1",
        "name": "issue1",
        "children": [] // Also could be null instead of []
    }, {
        "code": "is2",
        "name": "issue2",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "code": "is3",
        "name": "issue3",
        "children": [{
            "code": "is4",
            "name": "issue4",
            "children": []
        }, {
            "code": "is5",
            "name": "issue5",
            "children": []
        }]
    }]
},// The returned object.
html = "";

// Then, to create the checkbox list:

function createCheck(issue) {
    return "<input type='checkbox' id='" + issue.code + "' value='" + issue.code + "' /><label for='" + issue.code + "'>" + issue.name + "</label>";
}

function parseIssues(issues) {
    html += "<ul>";
    for (var i = 0; i < issues.length; i++) { 
        var issue = issues[i],
            input = createCheck(issue); // Creates the html for the checkbox
        html += "<li>" + input;
        if (issue.children.length > 0) {
            parseIssues(issue.children); // Calls a function which does similar to this for with the children.
        }
        html += "</li>";
    }
    html += "</ul>";
}

parseIssues(json.selectedissues);
document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = html;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/paska/wdb151m8/1/

However, if you want to stick with your data model, the right way to loop through it and generate the elements is this:

```
var html = "";// The returned object.

function createCheck(code, name) {
    return "<input type='checkbox' id='" + code + "' value='" + code + "' /><label for='" + code + "'>" + name + "</label>";
}

function parseIssues(issues) {
    html += "<ul>";
    for (var code in issues) {
        var issue = issues[code],
            name = typeof(issue) == "string" ? issue : issue.name, // Get the right name according to each element
            input = createCheck(code, name); // Creates the html for the checkbox
        html += "<li>" + input;
        if (issue.children) {
            parseIssues(issue.children); // Calls a function which does similar to this for with the children.
        }
        html += "</li>";
    }
    html += "</ul>";
}

parseIssues(json.selectedissues);
document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = html;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/paska/wdb151m8/2/

Comment: Overly verbose; there is little point in having the empty children arrays.

Comment: Was an example. They could be `null` instead of `[]`.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so much! I like the recursion, I didn't even think of doing it that way...

Comment: @Diego This is exactly what I am looking for. However, your jdfiddle does not contain any external resources. Which plugin do I have to include to get it working outside jsfiddle

Comment: @YashSaraiya, there are no plugins needed.

Comment: @Diego I simply copied your code in one of the editors and tried to run it, but that didn't worked. I included your json and js under a single script tag

Comment: @YashSaraiya, make sure you are adding the script at the bottom of the body element and that exists in the `DOM` the element where it sets the innerHTML. If it still doesn't work you can try to run the script in the document ready event

Answer (score 3):

First you need to parse this JSON into a JSON object:

```
var json = 'your json string here that you showed us above',
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

Now you do a for cycle for every object in the object from it.

```
for (var element in obj) {
    // Create checkbox here for every element
}
```

From here, you apply this method to your own code and needs. 
**Edited to fix with Diego's suggestion**

Comment: I don't think this would work. On one side you are missing the `selectedissues` prop. On the other hand, its value is an object (`{}`), not an array. `obj.length` wouldnt work.

Comment: This is not meant to apply to his specific example, it's a generic teaching of how JSON works, so that he could now work on it. Teach a man how to fish and he'll have fish for life, but give it a fish and he will starve the next day.

Comment: I agree with your quote, but still, to teach him how `JSON` works you should use `for (var key in obj)` and not `obj.length`

Comment: You're right. Edited. Only did it as so because he seemed to be new, and man people have difficulties understanding the foreach cycle, and rather sympathize with fori.

Comment: Yes, of course. I understand your point, but I I still want to emphasize that the `for` cycle wont work with a `JSON` :/

Comment: With this specific JSON you mean? It will work with normal JSON files.

Comment: You're absolutely right and I wasn't even thinking. It's what one gets by coding almost as zombie. Kek, thanks.

Comment: I actually have a huge amount of experience with JSON but literally none with js or web dev. Thanks though!